# Threading issue while testing LiveData and Coroutines

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-livedata, kotlin-coroutines

I have a weird bug occurring during testing that I am not able figure out.

This is my viewmodel -

```
class MediaViewModel constructor(repository: Repository) : ViewModel() {

    private var _media : LiveData<List<Media>> = repository.loadMediaForFolder(...)
    private val media = MediatorLiveData<List<Media>>()
    private var _sortOptions = Pair(MediaSortType.DATE_MODIFIED, false)

    init {
        media.addSource(_media) {
            viewModelScope.launch {
                media.value = sortMedia(it)
            }
        }
    }

    fun getMediaList(): LiveData<List<Media>> {
        return media
    }

    fun rearrangeMedia(sortType: MediaSortType, sortAsc: Boolean) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            val pair = Pair(sortType, sortAsc)
            if (_sortOptions != pair) {
                _sortOptions = pair

                _media.value?.let { media.value = sortMedia(it) }
            }
        }
    }

    private suspend fun sortMedia(mediaList: List<Media>)
            : List<Media> {
        return withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
            when (_sortOptions.second) {
                true -> when (_sortOptions.first) {
                    MediaSortType.NAME -> mediaList.sortedBy { it.mediaName }
                    MediaSortType.SIZE -> mediaList.sortedBy { it.size }
                    ...
                }
                false -> when (_sortOptions.first) {
                    MediaSortType.NAME -> mediaList.sortedByDescending { it.mediaName }
                    MediaSortType.SIZE -> mediaList.sortedByDescending { it.size }
                    ...
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Pretty simple viewmodel that sorts the repository data in `_media` in the background then updates the mediator livedata `media` , which is exposed as a plain livedata to the view.

The test class for this -

```
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
class MediaViewModelTest {

    private val folderDao = Mockito.mock(FolderDao::class.java)

    private lateinit var mediaViewModel: MediaViewModel

    private lateinit var repository: Repository

    @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
    @get:Rule
    var mainCoroutineRule = MainCoroutineRule()

    @get:Rule
    val instantTaskExecutorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

    @Before
    fun setupViewModel() {
        val mediaList = ...
        `when`(folderDao...).thenReturn(MutableLiveData(mediaList))

        repository = Repository(folderDao)
        mediaViewModel = MediaViewModel(repository)
    }

    @Test
    fun getMedia_sortBySizeDesc() {
        mediaViewModel.rearrangeMedia(MediaSortType.SIZE, false)

        val mediaListVm = LiveDataTestUtil.getValue(mediaViewModel.getMediaList())
        Truth.assertThat(mediaListVm).isInOrder { o1, o2 ->
            (o2 as Media).size.compareTo((o1 as Media).size)
        }
    }

    @Test
    fun getMedia_sortByNameAsc_thenByWidthDesc_thenByDateAsc() {
        mediaViewModel.rearrangeMedia(MediaSortType.NAME, true)

        var mediaListVm = LiveDataTestUtil.getValue(mediaViewModel.getMediaList())
        Truth.assertThat(mediaListVm).isInOrder { o1, o2 ->
            (o1 as Media).mediaName.compareTo((o2 as Media).mediaName)
        }

        mediaViewModel.rearrangeMedia(MediaSortType.WIDTH, false)

        mediaListVm = LiveDataTestUtil.getValue(mediaViewModel.getMediaList())
        Truth.assertThat(mediaListVm).isInOrder { o1, o2 ->
            (o2 as Media).width.compareTo((o1 as Media).width)
        }

        mediaViewModel.rearrangeMedia(MediaSortType.DATE_MODIFIED, true)

        mediaListVm = LiveDataTestUtil.getValue(mediaViewModel.getMediaList())
        Truth.assertThat(mediaListVm).isInOrder { o1, o2 ->
            (o1 as Media).dateModified.compareTo((o2 as Media).dateModified)
        }
    }
}
```

LiveDataTestUtil has been taken from [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/BasicSample/app/src/androidTest/java/com/example/android/persistence/LiveDataTestUtil.java)

I am trying to test whether my VM correctly sorts the data and for this I have two tests - one which does only a single sort and the other which applies a series of sorts, one after the other.

The issue is, the first test completes successfully but the second one fails while trying the second assert, i.e, the data fails to get sorted by width for some reason. However, if I run it in debug mode and step through, the test successfully completes. Also, I found that I can do a final assert but asserts in the middle fail. So this works -

```
   mediaViewModel.rearrangeMedia(MediaSortType.NAME, true)
   var media = LiveDataTestUtil.getValue(mediaViewModel.getMediaList())

   mediaViewModel.rearrangeMedia(MediaSortType.WIDTH, false)

   mediaViewModel.rearrangeMedia(MediaSortType.DATE_MODIFIED, true)
   Truth.assertThat(media).isInOrder { o1, o2 ->
       (o1 as Media).dateModified.compareTo((o2 as Media).dateModified)
   }
```

But this doesn't -

```
    mediaViewModel.rearrangeMedia(MediaSortType.NAME, true)
    val media = LiveDataTestUtil.getValue(mediaViewModel.getMediaList())
    Truth.assertThat(media).isInOrder { o1, o2 ->
        (o1 as Media).mediaName.compareTo((o2 as Media).mediaName)
    }

    mediaViewModel.rearrangeMedia(MediaSortType.WIDTH, false)
    Truth.assertThat(media).isInOrder { o1, o2 ->                // Fails
        (o2 as Media).width.compareTo((o1 as Media).width)
    }

    mediaViewModel.rearrangeMedia(MediaSortType.DATE_MODIFIED, true)
    Truth.assertThat(media).isInOrder { o1, o2 ->
        (o1 as Media).dateModified.compareTo((o2 as Media).dateModified)
    }
```

And this passes but also fails sometimes which means there's a race condition -

```
    mediaViewModel.rearrangeMedia(MediaSortType.NAME, true)
    Truth.assertThat(getValue(mediaViewModel.getMediaList())).isInOrder { o1, o2 ->
        (o1 as CachedMedia).mediaName.compareTo((o2 as CachedMedia).mediaName)
    }

    mediaViewModel.rearrangeMedia(MediaSortType.WIDTH, false)

    mediaViewModel.rearrangeMedia(MediaSortType.DATE_MODIFIED, true)
    Truth.assertThat(getValue(mediaViewModel.getMediaList())).isInOrder { o1, o2 ->
        (o1 as CachedMedia).dateModified.compareTo((o2 as CachedMedia).dateModified)
    }
```

What is happening here?